# How should I check the user's roles in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I'm doing a check on the logged in user's roles in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, to change a design element based on the role.

Is this a good way of doing it, or is there a better way?

```
int ix = User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin")
    ? 0
    : User.IsInRole("SysOp")
        ? 1
        : User.IsInRole("SupportAgent")
            ? 2
            : User.IsInRole("GroupAdmin")
                ? 3
                : User.IsInRole("GroupUser")
                    ? 4
                    : 5;
```

Then I use `ix` as an indexer in the `string[]` `btnDesign[]`:

```
class="btn @(btnDesign[ix])"
```

I'm aware that my check potentially causes five separate trips to the database, and that is why I'm asking this question.

**Update**
I have "optimized" it slightly. Seeing as there are more "GroupUser"s than "SiteAdmin"s, I turned the check on it's head (and removed one role, SupportAgent):

```
int ix = User.IsInRole("GroupUser")
    ? 0
    : User.IsInRole("GroupAdmin")
        ? 1
        : User.IsInRole("SysOp")
            ? 2
            : User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin")
                ? 3
                : 4;
```

Now the check will presumably be as fast as possible for the majority of the logged in users, which are "GroupUser"s.

Still, I would like to know if it is possible to improve it further.

Comment: what content in btnDesign array?

Comment: @HienNguyen Does that matter? It's strings like "btn-primary", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a mapping of roles to indices in a dictionary at some convenient place:

```
var roleMapping = new Dictionary<string,int>();
roleMapping.Add("SiteAdmin", 0);
...
```

In your code, you could retrieve all the roles of the user in one call:

```
var idUser = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
var roles = UserManager.GetRolesAsync(idUser).Result;
```

Now, determine the "most significant" index considering the roles that the user has through

```
int significantIndex = roleMapping
                         .Where(kv => roles.Contains(kv.Key))
                         .Select(kv => kv.Value)
                         .Min();
```

Here it is assumed that the index with the lowest value is the best match for the current user.